# What is preventing Ubuntu from displaying a screensaver?

Tags: command-line, screensaver

Is there a command to display current active processes that are preventing a screensaver from displaying?

- `gnome-screensaver` is installed
- `idle-activation-enabled` is set to true
- `idle-delay` is set
- dim option is enabled

Using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Did you found https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingScreenLocking and did you tried what is described there ?

Comment: its not a bug , there's a certain process that is preventing the screen saver from displaying , because if there is nothing running on the computer it will display property , I had the same issue in windows and there was a cmd command that displays active processes that are preventing screensaver from displaying .